# Read file using EUC-KR text encoding in R

Tags: r

Has anyone had experience to read Korean language file using EUC-KR as text encoding?

I used fread function as it can read that file structure perfectly. Below is the sample code:

```
test <- fread("KoreanTest.txt", encoding = "EUC-KR")
```

Then I got error, "Error in fread("KoreanTest.txt", encoding = "EUC-KR")  : Argument 'encoding' must be 'unknown', 'UTF-8' or 'Latin-1'".

Initially i was using UTF-8 as text encoding but the output characters were not displayed correctly in Korean language. I was looking to another solution but nothing seems to work at this time.

Appreciate if someone could share ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It allows an explicit encoding parameter. This common usage works well:

```
read.table(filesource, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "EUC-KR")
```

or you can try with Rstudio

> File -> Import Dataset -> From text

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I just found out that I just need to add a code in the early line:

    Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "korean")